# Ionic JWT Generation

Tags: ionic3, jwt

I know that JWT should be generated in the backend, however i need to generate it in the front-end, because the app runs fully offline and when connected it sends and receive data to/from backend.

I don’t know if it’s correct, but I’m trying to generate jwt inside ionic app and then send the jwt to backend to be validated to transfer data.

Anyone could help me and tell me a library to generate JWT inside ionic app or give an idea on how can i resolve this?

It's important that the app should work without internet connection. It has internet connection just sometimes.

Thank you very much.

My users database is in ionic native storage, because i need to realize login in the front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way...

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/third-party-libs/

Install node modules and import inside ionic app, using third party libs.

I have imported jwt-simple:

> $ npm i -s jwt-simple

And then:

```
import jwt from 'jwt-simple';
```